# JQuery Animate callback firing before animation is complete

Tags: jquery, callback, jquery-animate

I've been trying to look for some similar issue but I haven't found the exact same one.

I'm working with Masonry and I'm trying to slide a panel with filters from one side into the Masonry ul. Then, when the animation is complete, I want Masonry to stamp the panel and recalculate distribution of the rest of items. Callback function seems to be the perfect choice, but I can't make it work ... the callback is called before the animation is fully completed so some items are repositioned just under the panel.

This is the code:

```
filterButton.off('click').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!filters.hasClass("open")) {
        filters.animate({ right: 0 }, 300, function () {
            masonryZone.masonry('stamp', filters);
            masonryZone.masonry('layout');
        });
        filters.addClass("open");
    } else {
        filters.animate({ right: -395 }, 300, function () {
            masonryZone.masonry('unstamp', filters);
            masonryZone.masonry('layout');
        });
        filters.removeClass("open");
    }

});
```

filters is just one object, in case you are wondering. So callback should be fired just once.
I've tried the promise() option with the same result.
I've tried setTimeout() option and it works, but it looks like nonsense to use a timeout to avoid complete function of being fired before it's suposed to!

And the funny part of the issue is that the second part of the code works as expected (the "else" part).

Sorry about my english and thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you create a basic [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) displaying the issue?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what's going wrong but I'd guess it is something to do with Masonry, as evidenced by the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nunners/DByc2/), the functionality works fine and the callback function is only called once the animation is finished.

Comment: I was creating the Fiddle and then I realized what was the problem: the css of the filter panel had "transform-dutation" set to .2s, so I guess that was triggering the event before the JQuery animation was really completed. Sorry about it, and thanks anyway to everyone that tried to help me!

Comment: As I'm a total noob in StackOverFlow ... how can I mark this question as solved? Should I answer myself explaining the problem and mark that as the accepted answer?

Comment: If you've found a solution yourself then yes, please share it :)

Comment: As I have no reputation, I have to wait a few hours before I can answer to my own question. I'll do it asap. Thanks again.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Problem was my CSS. I had this rules on my filters panel:

```
transition-duration: .2s;
-moz-transition-duration: .2s;
-webkit-transition-duration: .2s;
```

So I'm quite sure CSS animation was missguiding JQuery, triggering the "complete" event before JQuery animation was fully completed. Once I removed that part of my CSS code, everything was working as expected.

Thanks for your help and sorry again about the time I made you waste on this.

Comment: oh lawd, I spent like two hours figuring out what was the problem. This is a "must-check-you-don't" answer.

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaahahahahahahahaha. i can't believe i made this mistake. this saved me a lot of hair pulling. ty ahahaha ty

Comment: Great ! totally missed that.

Comment: ooooooooooooooooohh man, this has been bugging me for years. I thought it was a bug with jquery. thanks!!

Comment: Hahaha I'm glad this keeps helping people, it almost drove me crazy. And it's actually kind of a bug with jQuery, even thought I realize it's quite hard to check if the CSS properties have changed because of jQuery animate function or CSS animation...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `complete` for that.

```
complete:  function() { //do something on animation finishes
 }
```

**[See Complete in Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)**

Comment: He's using the first method overload where the `complete` handler is passed as a parameter and not as a property of an `object`

Comment: Cant he use it that way then??

Comment: I already used that option, and it works exactly the same way

Comment: would be great if you can create the fiddle.